# C# library similar to Unity's Transform component

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, transform, geospatial

I use Unity to make a number of small engineering specific applications, because I find the Transform component and the Quaternion and Vector3 classes have some great native functionality that makes spatial work much easier.

I need to step outside the Unity editor/engine for some projects, and was wondering if there is a C# library with similar functionality that is highly portable that I could drop into a VS project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find Unity's source code implementation for the classes / structs you mentioned here:

Vector3: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs

Quaternion: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Quaternion.cs

Transform - related stuff: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/tree/master/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings

Perhaps you can use this code as reference or even copy it in your project. Mind you, I do not know what the licence permits or not.

Comment: The licence is highly restricting! The code has "reference purpose" only: https://unity3d.com/legal/licenses/Unity_Reference_Only_License
You need a Pro Licence for Unity for usage of their code directly.

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the best for you work is [Vim.Math3D](https://github.com/vimaec/Math3D), the package contais classes for

- Vectors

  ```
   Vector2 - Single precision X, Y
   Vector3 - Single precision X, Y, Z
   Vector4 - Single precision X, Y, Z, W
   DVector2 - Double precision X, Y, Z
   DVector3 - Single precision X, Y, Z
   DVector4 - Single precision X, Y, Z, W
   Int2 - Integer X, Y
   Int3 - Integer X, Y, Z
   Int4 - Integer X, Y
   Complex - Double precision Imaginary, Real
  ```
- Pseudo-Vectors - the following classes lack some of the operations of
  Vectors

  ```
   Byte2 - Byte X, Y
   Byte3 - Byte X, Y, Z
   Byte4 - Byte X, Y, Z, W
   ColorRGB - Byte representation of color R, G, B
   ColorRGBA - Byte representation of color with Alpha R, G, B, A
   ColorHDR - High Defintion Range color representation, 4 floats, R, G, B, A
  ```
- Rotations and Transformations

  ```
   Quaternion - Single precision quaternion rotation X, Y, Z, W
   DQuaternion - Single precision quaternion rotation X, Y, Z, W
   AxisAngle - Single precison rotation as Axis (Vector3) and Angle in radians
   Matrix4x4 - 4 x 4 Single Precision matrix in Row-Column - corder
   Transform - Single precision Position (Vector3) and Orientation (Quaternion)
   Euler - Single precision Euler engle rotation as Yaw (Z rotation), Pitch (X rotation), Roll (y rotation)
  ```
- Geometric structures and shapes

  ```
   Plane - Single precision plane stored Normal (Vector3) and D (distance along normal from Origin)
   DPlane - Double precision plane stored Normal (Vector3) and D (distance along normal from Origin)
   Triangle - Single precision representation of triangle in 3 dimension as 3 Vector3 Points, A, B, and C
   Triangle2 - Single precision representation of triangle in 3 dimension as 3 Vector3 Points, A, B, and C
   Quad - Single precision representation of quadrilateral in 3 dimension as 4 Vector3 Points, A, B, C, and D
   DQuad - Double precision representation of quadrilateral in 3 dimension as 4 Vector3 Points, A, B, C, and D
  ```
- Lines

  ```
   Line - Single precision line segment A and B
   Ray - Single precision Point and Direction in 3 dimensional space
   DRay - Double precision Point and Direction in 3 dimensional space
  ```
- Interval and Bounding Structure

  ```
   Interval - Single precision float interval (float Min, float Max)
   AABox - Single precision 3 dimensional axis-aligned bouncing box (Vector3 Min, Vector3 Max)
   AABox2D - Single precision 2 dimensional axis-aligned bouncing box (Vector2 Min, Vector2 Max)
   AABox4D - Single precision 4 dimensional axis-aligned bouncing box (Vector4 Min, Vector4 Max)
   DInterval - Double precision float interval (double Min, double Max)
   DAABox - Double precision 3 dimensional axis-aligned bouncing box (DVector3 Min, DVector3 Max)
   DAABox2D - Double precision 2 dimensional axis-aligned bouncing box (DVector2 Min, DVector2 Max)
   DAABox4D - Double precision 4 dimensional axis-aligned bouncing box (DVector4 Min, DVector4 Max)
   Sphere - Bounding sphere (Vector3 Center, float Radius)
   DSphere - Double precision bounding spehere (DVector3 Center, double Radius)
  ```
- Alternative Coordinate Representations

  ```
   SphericalCoordinate - Radius, Azimuth (bearing), and Inclination (elevation angle)
   PolarCoordinate - Radius and Azimuth (bearing)
   LogPolarCoordinate - Rho (log of radial distance) and Azimuth
   CylindricalCoordinate - Radius, Azimuth (bearing) and Height
   HorizontalCoordinate - Azimuth (bearing) and Inclination
   GeoCoordinate - Latitude and Longitude
  ```
- Motion

  ```
   LinearMotion - Velocity, Acceleration, and Scalar Friction
   AngularMotion - Velocity, Acceleration, and Scalar Friction
   Motion - LinearMotion and AngularMotion
  ```

You can also check some libraries related to the above

[System.Numerics](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics,namespaces)

[SharpDX Mathematics](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/tree/master/Source/SharpDX.Mathematics)

[MonoGame](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame)

[Math.NET Spatial](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-spatial)

[Math.NET Numerics](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics)

[Stride](https://github.com/stride3d/stride/tree/master/sources/core/Stride.Core.Mathematics)